# How do you implicitly differentiate $y$ from $y\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 15$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I've been working on this problem for the last 45 minutes, and I keep getting the wrong answer, no matter what I do. I tried squaring the whole equation, so that there was no radical to deal with - didn't work. I tried the product rule + chain rule  - didn't work. Is anyone able to explain how to do it? I'm really desperate.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hint:
You may begin by noting that $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=15\qquad\iff\qquad x^2+y^2=225$$

Answer (score 2):

$$(x^2+y^2)^\frac 12 = 15$$
differentiating ...
$$(x^2+y^2)^{-\frac 12}(2x+2yy') = 0$$
clearly only the second factor can be zero so

$$y'=-\frac xy $$

as required for a circle (slope of tangent is the negative reciprocal of the slope of the radius )

Comment: I thought the expression is $y (x^2+y^2)^\frac 12 = 15$

Comment: @ja72 The question was changed after I posted my answer

Answer (score 2):

Assume $y(x)$ is a function of $x$ on an open domain around $(x_0,y_0)$, then:
$$
0=\left(y(x)\sqrt{y(x)^2+x^2}-15\right)'=y'(x)\sqrt{y(x)^2+x^2}+y(x)\frac{y(x)y'(x)+x}{\sqrt{y(x)^2+x^2}}\Leftrightarrow
$$
$$
0=y'(x)\left(2y(x)^2+x^2\right)+xy(x)\Rightarrow y'(x)=-\frac{xy(x)}{2y(x)^2+x^2}
$$
Meaning:
$$
y'=-\frac{xy(x)}{2y^2+x^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You have $f(x,y)=C$ and apply the chain rule

$$ \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} {\rm d}x + \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} {\rm d} y = 0 $$

In your case

$$ \frac{x y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} {\rm d}x + \frac{x^2+2 y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} {\rm d} y = 0 $$

$$ \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} = - \frac{x y}{x^2+2 y^2} $$